# How to make this dataframe update more efficient?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
            print(index)
            alias = row['alias']
            synonym = row['synonym']
            original_name = row['original_name']
            new_alias = ''
            if alias:
                new_alias += alias
            if synonym:
                new_alias += '|' + synonym
            if original_name:
                new_alias += '|' + original_name
            row['alias'] = new_alias
            df[index] = row
```

This conditionally update each and write the row back to the DF row by row. It works but very slow. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow mainly because you are trying to update the data every iteration. Instead, do a loop comprehension, or `apply`. Something like this:

```
# this only joins non-empty elements
my_join = lambda x: '|'.join([a for a in x.unique() if a])

df['alias'] = df[['alias','synonym', 'original_name']].apply(my_join, axis=1)
```

Comment: How to avoid the duplicate ones, if a from alias and b from synonym are the same? In this case, I only want to keep one of them.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't get rid of the duplicate. Is unique() a numpy function not python?